# Django – Require at least one instance of ManyToOne model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to require at least one ManyToOne instance to a model when it's (first) saved? The idea is, to have a product that can have a price history (hope using a separate, loosely-coupled model for this is the right approach); so in order to add a product, at least one price should be required.
I read that it's smarter to put this kind of validation into `clean` rather than `save`, as `ValidationError`s are not raised from the latter and it's simply "better by convention". Not 100% sure where to draw the line regarding those two methods yet though.

Currently trying to get it to work with Django admin; code looks as follows

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def clean(self):
        if self._state.adding:
            if not self.prices.count():
                raise ValidationError({
                'prices': ('At least one product price is required'),
            })

class ProductPrice(models.Model):
    product: Product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prices')
    price: float = models.FloatField()
    created: datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


# admin.py
class ProductPriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    readonly_fields = ('created',)
    model = ProductPrice
    extra = 3
    can_delete = False

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductInline(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    verbose_name = 'Product'
    inlines = [ProductPriceInline,]
```

And getting `ValueError ProductForm has no field named prices`. Also tried using a constraint on `Product` instead (`models.CheckConstraint(check=~Q(prices=None), name='at_least_1_non_null'),]`) but tbh I'm just really overwhelmed with all the different solution possibilities, finding the right one and/or finding out how I can fix what's wrong with the current one. Really glad for any pointers besides the main issue here.

edit: on a side note – just realized the `clean` method will always return `self.prices.count()` with 0, as the `ProductPrice` instance is only created *after* `Product` has been created and can therefore be referenced by the former.